# Function vs fat arrow

Tags: javascript, function, oop, callback

So, if we take this `function` for example:

```
function executeCallback (callback) {
  callback();
}
```

Now, it doesn't matter if I place a `fat arrow` or a normal `function`, both will work, like these:

```
executeCallback(function () {
  alert('This is a function');
})

executeCallback(() => {
  alert('This is a fat arrow function');
})
```

So, except for shorter syntax. What exactly is the difference between both and how does it effect object oriented programming?

Comment: The way `this` is bound differs fundamentally. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - oh also there can be an implicit `return`

Comment: I did notice that indeed. But is that the only difference between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more in depth info, see this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/804928). Also, See this [here](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies).

### A Few Reasons

---

### **More intuitive handling of current object context.**

**ES6 Arrow**

```
this.nums.forEach((v) => {
    if (v % 5 === 0)
        this.fives.push(v) //this actually points to the context of the callback
});
```

**Ecmascript 5**

```
//  variant 1
var self = this;
this.nums.forEach(function (v) {
    if (v % 5 === 0)
        self.fives.push(v);
});

//  variant 2
this.nums.forEach(function (v) {
    if (v % 5 === 0)
        this.fives.push(v);
}, this);

//  variant 3 (since ECMAScript 5.1 only)
this.nums.forEach(function (v) {
    if (v % 5 === 0)
        this.fives.push(v);
}.bind(this));
```

### **More expressive closure syntax.**

**ES6 Arrow**

```js
odds  = evens.map(v => v + 1)
pairs = evens.map(v => ({ even: v, odd: v + 1 }))
nums  = evens.map((v, i) => v + i)
```

**Ecmascript 5**

```
odds  = evens.map(function (v) { return v + 1; });
pairs = evens.map(function (v) { return { even: v, odd: v + 1 }; });
nums  = evens.map(function (v, i) { return v + i; });
```

Answer (score 0):

- the arrow function automatically bind the current context to the this so you won't need to do `myfunction.bind(this, args)`